# WMATweetView with Swift and Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, swift

I'm trying to use [`WMATweetView`](https://github.com/markbeaton/WMATweetView) with Swift in Xcode 6.0.1. I've successfully used it in Objective-C. In my Swift project I've made a bridge and imported it. However, the problem I have is that the tapped `func`s are not invoked. Maybe I'm doing something wrong when I set the tapped methods (e.g, urlTapped) or I've overlooked something. I've added an `NSLog()` in `WMATweetView.m` to make sure that at least that method is invoked:

```
- (void)viewTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapRecognizer
{
    NSLog(@"viewTapped");
    if (tapRecognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
    {
        return;
    }

    // entity is always nil here urlTapped is not null
    WMATweetEntity* entity = [self entityForGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];

    if ([entity isKindOfClass:[WMATweetURLEntity class]] && self.urlTapped != NULL)
    {
        self.urlTapped((WMATweetURLEntity *)entity, tapRecognizer.numberOfTouches);
    }
    ...
}
```

When I debug the viewTapped method I see that urlTapped is not null but the entity object in that method always is.

Here's the base code I use in viewDidLoad to instantiate `WMATweetView`:

```
var tweetView = WMATweetView(text: "Tweet with a link http://example.com, screen name     @wemakeapps, #hashtag, more text, another link http://example.net @ZarroBoogs #ios moo",     frame: CGRectMake(100, 100, 200, 200))

tweetView.setupDefaults()   // This is required otherwise there's no "viewTapped" print at all
self.view.addSubview(tweetView)
```

In my `ViewController` class I have this:

```
func tapped(entity : WMATweetURLEntity!, numberOfTouches: UInt )
{
    println("tapped")
}
```

Here are the different ways I've tried to set the `urlTapped` method (in `viewDidLoad`):

```
// 1
let t : URLEntityTappedCallbackBlock = tapped
tweetView.urlTapped = t
// 2
tweetView.urlTapped = tapped
// 3
tweetView.urlTapped = {(entity : WMATweetURLEntity!, numberOfTouches: UInt ) -> () in
    println("urlTapped")
}
```

Does anybody have any clue of what I am doing wrong? Or have any tips of other tweet label controls (I've tried `STTweetLabel` as well but it seems to crash randomly?) ?

Comment: I just implemented this in Swift successfully. Try returning Void instead of () :)

Answer (score -1):

I just implemented this in Swift successfully. Try returning Void instead of () :)